# Create website with a switch between private and business

Tags: multisite, customization

I'm about to set up a website of a certain company which has private and business customers.

- There's going to be a switch (private/business) in the top left corner of the website.
- Both sections have different main menu's.
- A cookie should be set when visitor choose their customer type and customers should be redirected the second time they visit.

I just read about creating a Wordpress multisite for this. Is that the correct solution? Or are there other (better) solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

How I see you can implement this is:

https://example.com - This is the landing page/site where you have a menu on the top left and a user can choose "Private" or "Business". You can set a cookie based on what user clicked on.

https://example.com/private/ - This could be an inner page which has it's own template and loads a menu for private site OR this could be set up as a WordPress installation in a /private subdirectory

https://example.com/business/ - This could be an inner page which has it's own template and loads a menu for business site OR this could be set up as a WordPress installation in a /business subdirectory

Next time when user lands on https://example.com your landing page template shall read the cookie and redirect the user to appropriate site.

I hope this helps. WordPress multisite is useful if you need to offer similar WordPress websites to a large number of users. So check your use case and keep multisite as last option.

Comment: Why MultiSite as a last option and why would it only be useful for large numbers? Having /private and /business as part of one MultiSite is a perfect use case in my opinion

Comment: @kero please check [this article](https://pressable.com/blog/2016/02/11/what-is-wordpress-multisite-and-when-should-you-use-it/) for more details.

Comment: This doesn't really answer anything, it is just someones point of view. "WordPress.com is, by far, is the largest example of a Multisite network" - aren't the sites there very, very different? So "WordPress Multisite emerged at a time when there just weren’t a lot of good options for managing multiple and very different WordPress sites" doesn't make sense to me. I've personally managed small and larger MultiSite networks, while some plugins only have generic settings, this was never a problem as this usually was something that each site would have shared anyway

Comment: True, WordPress.com is the fact but look at a scale at which it is being used & the maintenance staff behind it. On shared hosting, we don't get full control of the configs and another problem is if the main site is at stake then it also affects the entire network. Hence, keeping WordPress multisite as last option is my point of view. It's not like it's not an option/solution at all. I think Rick can choose either way based on his use case - scale and maintenance capacity :)

Answer (score 0):

Multisite doesn't sound like the right solution. What you wanna do is have two different Wordpress menus when you switch private/business. And then you can store the version of the site your customer was last viewing in a cookie (private or business).